# vmcomputeagent.exe NOT FOUND on starting docker windows container - very simple Dockerfile

Tags: docker, .net-4.8

Dockerfile :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8
WORKDIR /app

COPY  WebApi.exe /app

RUN ls

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/WebApi.exe"]
```

Command used to build image and then run container:

```
docker build -t hello .

docker run -d -t --name helloContainer hello
```

Error :

> ca82a2934274e45abb991ec357d32de28d6ce4da092d6634af8a74c8f4106185
> docker: Error response from daemon: container
> ca82a2934274e45abb991ec357d32de28d6ce4da092d6634af8a74c8f4106185
> encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in
> a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified.
> (0x2)  [Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
> [Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
> [Event Detail:
> onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF7B789A41B:
> (caller: 00007FF7B7855BDB) Exception(2) tid(3b4) 80070002 The system
> cannot find the file specified.
> CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
> Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]  extra info:
> {"CommandLine":"/app/WebApi.exe","WorkingDirectory":"C:\app","Environment":{"COMPLUS_NGenProtectedProcess_FeatureEnabled":"0","DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER":"true","DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER":"true","NUGET_VERSION":"5.5.1","ROSLYN_COMPILER_LOCATION":"C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn"},"EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[55,237]}.